# How to get a specific element from a jQuery object by its attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, attributes

I have a website with a couple of elements like this:

```
<g class="box" rel="1">...</g>
<g class="box" rel="2">...</g>
<g class="box" rel="3">...</g>
<g class="box" rel="4">...</g>
<g class="box" rel="5">...</g>
```

In my code I want to change some attributes of these elements in a loop. What I have done at first was this (it works fine for me):

```
for(var i = 0, l = relValList.length; i < l; i+=1){
    $(".box[rel=" + relValList[i] + "]").children().first().attr("fill","#000000");
}
```

Now I have read a jQuery best practices article, where i found something called caching to increase the performance.

So I try it.

```
//call this when page loaded
var boxes = $(".box");

//the good old loop
for(var i = 0, l = relValList.length; i < l; i+=1){
   //here is my problem
   boxes ????
}
```

What is the best way to get a specific element from boxes by its rel attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). It applies a selector to an existing jQuery selection.

```
box.filter("[rel=" + relValList[i] + "]").children().first().attr("fill","#000000");
```

Alternatively, you do not even have to loop over the boxes. You can match the first child of every box having a `rel` attribute like this:

```
$('.box[rel] :first-child').attr("fill","#000000");
```

Comment: It is. Looking up by class otherwise happens every iteration, like this it happens just once. Once is faster than n times.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I'm looking for!! Works perfect and I got a much better performance (tested on mobile Safari, iPad 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method, it iterates through the selected elements and returns the matching ones. `filter` method is much faster than chained strings selectors.

```
var $boxes = $(".box"),
    $goldenOnes = $boxes.filter('[rel="golden"]');
```